# New Install of MF 7.1 on OSx. Hybrid applications are generate invalid messages.json file

Tags: json, macos, ibm-mobilefirst

I've tried this twice and get the same issue.  I installed MobileFirst into Eclipse Luna.  I create a Hybrid project and add an environment (doesn't matter which one).  With out making any changes to the generated code, I do a build.  When the build is done, I get an error in the following file.

/Kenn/apps/kenn/iphone/native/www/default/worklight/messages/es line 31 JSON Problem

The error is a missing quote and comma at the end of a line in the JSON file generated by the tool.  If you try to fix it, it will be regenerated.

Below is a snippet of what is being generated in the messages file:

```
"directUpdateNotificationMessageKilobytes" : "Hay disponibles nuevos recursos web. ¿Desea descargarlos ahora? (tamaño de archivo: {0} KB).
"directUpdateErrorTitle" : "Actualización fallida",
```

Comment: What is on line 31, and what is the exact error message?

Comment: The exact message is "String is not properly closed by a matching quote.".  The Spanish version of the worklight messages.json file is not being generated correctly.  If you scroll to the right on the file snippet you will see it is missing.  Problem is that if you correct it, the file is regenerated by worklight and becomes corrupted again when you build.

Comment: Hmmm... seems like an encoding issue, and bug perhaps. I'd recommend contacting the developer.

Comment: I don't have an immediate answer for you, but I can tell you that I've seen this exact problem, in this exact place, myself.  Looking into it further....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a new defect.  From my testing, I first notice the issue in 7.1 iFix build IF20151104-1620.  I've also confirmed that it is present in IF20151107-1647.  However, my testing indicates that it is not present in IF20151103-1015, or prior builds.

I've opened APAR PI52202 to report the defect.

Comment: thanks, I did some testing and grabbed the GA version of the P2 eclipse install for 7.1 and the problem is not there.  Looks like it is just when you install from the eclipse market place.

Comment: I think the Eclipse Marketplace version is ahead of what's available on IBM Fix Central - last time I looked, the most recent build there was from end of October, and doesn't have this issue.